# if condition, then upsert else do nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to upsert a value only if a condition is true, otherwise I dont want to do anything to the record. My code seems to generate primary key errors when I run it again (indicating the insert is firing, but the whole statement should be skipped)

Error on second run: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__chicken__A2D9E564407C90CD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.chicken'. The duplicate key value is (10118-78843).`

Query:

```
IF((select status from chicken where [PrimaryKey]='10118-78843')!='paid')
update [eComm]..[chicken] set [Status]='Overdue' where [PrimaryKey]='10118-78843' 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into [eComm]..[chicken]([PrimaryKey],[Status]) values('10118-78843','Paid');
```

create example table code:

```
create table chicken(
PrimaryKey nvarchar(50) not null,
Status nvarchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (PrimaryKey)
)
```

Goal (this is invalid syntax):

```
IF((select status from chicken where [PrimaryKey]='10118-78843')!='paid')
{
update [eComm]..[chicken] set [Status]='Overdue' where [PrimaryKey]='10118-78843' 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into [eComm]..[chicken]([PrimaryKey],[Status]) values('10118-78843','Paid');
}
```

else, do nothing

Comment: @Larnu I corrected my example code, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: If the existing row status is `paid`, the row will not be updated and your code tries to insert a duplicate.

Comment: THINK! What happens when the row exists and the status IS 'paid'? The IF evaluate to false, @@rowcount IS zero, and you attempt to insert a row that has the same PK value.

Comment: @DanGuzman that is what is throwing me off. how do I do an IF something else nothing? I just updated my post with an example of my goal that is incorrect syntax, but it is what I am trying to figure out how to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not taking into account what happens if there is an existing row but the status is `paid`.

You need to tweak the logic a bit:

```sql
declare @status varchar(20) = (
    select c.status
    from chicken c
    where c.[PrimaryKey] = '10118-78843'
);

if (@status != 'paid')
    update [chicken]
    set [Status] = 'Overdue'
    where [PrimaryKey] = '10118-78843';
else if (@status is null)
    insert into [chicken] ([PrimaryKey], [Status])
    values ('10118-78843', 'Paid');
```

Alternatively:

```sql
insert into [chicken] ([PrimaryKey], [Status])
select '10118-78843', 'Paid'
where not exists (select 1
    from chicken c
    where c.[PrimaryKey] = '10118-78843'
);

if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    update [chicken]
    set [Status] = 'Overdue'
    where [PrimaryKey] = '10118-78843'
      and status != 'Paid';
```

Comment: The second example was exactly what I needed! the first one added multiple rows if run more than once

Comment: You're right there was a bug, have modified